# AutoSmusher for amazon S3 to optimise images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, optimization, amazon-s3, paperclip

Any ruby implementation with paperclip to autosmush amazon s3 images?

PS: I googled and got this: https://github.com/grosser/smusher and works pretty nicely on my local machine. But to use something like this on amazon s3. It will be great to have an automated process for this and just smush newly created content. Any ideas?

Code I am using to some what optimise user uploaded images.

```
has_attached_file :attachment, {
    :styles => {
      :medium => ["654x5000000>", :jpg],
      :small => ["260x50000000>", :jpg], 
      :thumb => ["75x75#", :jpg],
      :facebook_meta_tag =>["200x200#", :jpg] 
    },
    :convert_options => {
       :medium => "-quality 80 -interlace Plane",
       :small => "-quality 80 -interlace Plane",
       :thumb => "-quality 80 -interlace Plane",
       :facebook_meta_tag => "-quality 80 -interlace Plane" 
       },
       :s3_headers => { 'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000', 'Expires' => 10.years.from_now.httpdate } 
    }.merge(PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS)
```

But still images can be optimised. I got the gem smusher but confused how to use it. My current page ranking as per GTmetrics is here.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also been looking into lossless image compression with rails, and so far I think the best gem I have found is [here](https://github.com/dakick/paperclip-compression). The instructions with the gem say to add a `:processors` option that gets passed a hash containing multiple processing options, such as `:compression`, which this gem defines. It also requires jpgtran and optipng to be installed, which I'm not sure if Amazon S3 has.